# Introductive section at the beginning of a chapter

Tags: chapters, thesis

I am writing my thesis and at the beginning of each chapter I would like to make a general overview and come up with a page as shown in the attached image. Does anyone know what is the right command to use? [image]

Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What are the specifications, in addition to being typeset in italic?

Comment: You can try the quote or quotation environment.

Comment: What kind of specifications (sorry, I am just at the beginning of the process of writing)? The idea is to create a different page at the beginning of each chapter with just the title and a brief introduction. Then, officially start the beginning of the chapter in the next page (with the first subsection).

Comment: Ok, I have solved it by using the quoting environment by using the package \usepackage[font=itshape]{quoting}